# Up! mini raft sticking to prints

Tags: abs

I have an UP! mini and I am using the UP Studio and ABS 1.75 mm.

My prints are always stuck to the rafts and are impossible to remove without destroying the print.

I've had a look at the settings on the Up Studio but I don't know which ones to change to improve the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the print is made to separate easily from the raft by minimizing layer adhesion between the first layer of the actual part and the last layer of the raft.

If this isn't happening with your prints, you likely need to adjust some settings in your slicer.  You need to ensure that the first part layer is more than a normal layer height above the top raft layer (in Cura Slicer, I believe this would be the First Layer Thickness); this should be comparable to the Z distance allowance for supports to be removable.  You may also want or need to adjust the line width and temperature for the first part layer -- too wide a line may stick too well, and if the first layer is too hot, the same will occur.

It may require several test prints to find just the right settings, though I'd start with resetting your slicer to its default for the printer and materials you're using, and start any adjustments from that base.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be much documentation on that particular proprietary software, but in conventional slicers, the setting you are looking for is called the "raft air gap". This should be a distance value slightly higher than your regular layer height.

So if printing with 0.2 mm layer height, do 0.28 mm or something of the sort. Check to see if your UP studio slicer has advanced settings and find something along those lines.